# GetWindowRect function is returning zeros for Solidworks Applications

Tags: vba, solidworks, solidworksapi

I am trying to get the location of a solidworks window on my screen. I'm using the GetWindowRect function to do this. This works for all applications I've tried, except for Solidworks Applications. This is a Solidworks macro so its written in VBA:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String _
) As LongPtr
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
    lpRect As RECT _
) As Long

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    right As Long
    bottom As Long
End Type

Private this As RECT

Public Sub swWindow(lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String)

    Dim hwnd As LongPtr
    hwnd = FindWindow(lpClassName, lpWindowName)
    
    Dim check As long
    check = GetWindowRect(hwnd, this)
    
    Debug.Print Err.LastDllError
    
End Sub
```

I get locations for all tested applications (excel, txt, etc), but Solidworks Applications only returns zero values.

- The "FindWindow" method does return a handle (724300)
- The "GetWindowRect" method returns a value of 1 (check variable), which means the function was successful.
- The Err.LastDllError is zero, which indicates nothing went wrong.

But my actual locations being return are all zeros. Anybody out there ran into a similar problem, or know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842745/get-window-position-of-a-visio-application).

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. That post uses thisDocument, which is unique to visio (and maybe word?). But it does not exists for Solidworks. Further more, I don't see how this line `GetWindowRect this.Handle, this.rc` is any different than how I'm doing it. I will be using this for a form, so I'll likely need to use the conversion method (pixel to point), but that wont work until I'm able to get non-zero values from the getwindowrect method.

Comment: Agreed... I never worked in SolidWors (and Visio neither and I thought that the thread may help). Do you have Spy++ or something similar? If yes, do you see the respective window in it? Since, you can find the window handler I cannot imagine how to not return its `Rect`. It shouldn't matte if the form exposes or not its position. The respective API should return `Rect` of the respective (found) window. Unfortunately, I do not have SolidWorks installed to see/test if there is a way to make it working.

Comment: Thanks for trying. The post was insightful. This is running in a vba editor, not visual studios. I don't know what spy++ is, but from a quick read up, it seems its part of visual studios. I can look into it later. The program works as is... It would just be better if the form showed up in the right spot, which is what I'm trying to do with this code snip. But its not super high priority for me since it does technically work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Solidworks Applications only returns zero values"? Did `FindWindow` return zero, too? If so, where from you have `lpClassName` without using a windows spy application to see it? It (theoretically) can be different of the ones returning the handler...

Comment: `check = GetWindowRect(hwnd, this)`.  `this` is a RECT Structure. It is passed by reference. Once the function is called, all four members of the structure are populated with the window location. But mine are all zero. In my application, `lpClassName` is null, I call the `FindWindow` method using the `lpWindowName` parameter. It is not returning zero, was returning 724300 for my pointer. The `getWindowRect` method was returning a value of 1, which means the function succeeded. But all members in `this` were zero (I tried initializing them, they are being overriden with zeros).

Comment: I have figured out the problem, but not a good solution yet. Typing in the windows caption for ipWindowName returned a child window handle. I wrote a lengthy script to loop through each window I had opened on my screen, and I found the parent solidworks window. I used that handle and I got my location values. I'm still working on a clean script to get the parent window handle.

Comment: Without Spy++ or something similar it is difficult to determine the parent window. Otherwise, it should be easy...

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my `lpWindowName` was referencing a child window instead of the parent window. The caption at the top of the screen is the file name. If you use this for `lpWindowname`, then you'll get the child handle. The correct format to get the parent is "SOLIDWORKS Premium 2022 SP4.0 - [filename]"

To generate this programmatically for the currently active document, and get its parent handler, I did the following:

```
#If Win64 Then

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String _
    ) As LongPtr
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
        lpRect As rect _
    ) As Long
#Else

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String _
    ) As Long
    
    Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        lpRect As rect _
    ) As Long
    
#End If


Private Type rect
    left As Long
    top As Long
    right As Long
    bottom As Long
End Type


Private Type swType
    app As SldWorks.SldWorks
    model As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    draw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
End Type

Private Type thisType
    sw As swType
End Type

Private this As thisType

Public Sub centerForm(ByRef myForm As IUserForm)
    Dim windLoc As rect
    Dim boolCheck As Long
    boolCheck = GetWindowRect(windowHandle, windLoc)
end sub



'Returns the window handle for the solidworks model.
#If Win64 Then
    Private Function windowHandle() As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Function windowHandle() As Long
#End If

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = this.sw.model.getTitle
    
    'this dirtyFlag (astrisk) is added to the caption name when anything
    '   in the solidworks document is not saved or up to date.
    Dim dirtyFlag As String
    If this.sw.model.GetSaveFlag Then _
        dirtyFlag = " *"
    
    Dim caption As String
    caption = swTitle & " - [" & fileName & dirtyFlag & "]"
    
    windowHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, caption)
    
End Function



'The swApp.RevisionNumber method returns a major.minor version number
'   The major number correlates with the release year, starting with
'   major version 8 for the year 2000, with the year and major version
'   incrementing each year. So the year 2022 will have major version 30
'   The following equation will convert the major version into a year:
'       year = 2000 + major revision - 8
'   The minor version is the service pack (SP) number
Private Function swTitle() As String
    
    'The swTitle should look something like this:
    '   SOLIDWORKS Premium 2022 SP4.0
    
    Dim revision() As String
    revision = split(this.sw.app.RevisionNumber, ".")
    
    Const INITIAL_YEAR As Long = 2000
    Const INITIAL_REV As Long = 8
    Dim year As String
    year = INITIAL_YEAR + revision(0) - INITIAL_REV
    
    Dim SP As String
    SP = revision(1) & "." & revision(2)

    swTitle = "SOLIDWORKS Premium " & year & " SP" & SP
    
End Function
```